# Using a URL scheme to the apple translation app, can I get text from anki, and then when I click on URL open translate app and translate?

Tags: ios, applications, url

Sorry for the stupid wording, I'm really new to this.

I'm trying to essentially create a URL to the apple translate app, so that when I click on the URL it automatically translates text from my anki app.

here is an example I have of one working with another app

```
<a class="japanese ios-only" href="mkdictionaries:///?text={{VocabKanji}}&category=ja&srcname=Anki&src=anki://">大辞林</a>
```

So ideally what I would have is something like this, if it was possible.

```
<a class="japanese ios-only" href="translate:///?text={{SentKanji}}&category=ja&srcname=Anki&src=anki://">Translate</a>
```

Please let me know if there is any solution.

I greatly appreciate the help thanks

Perhaps if this isn't possible is there a workaround using the shortcuts app?